# How can I send an email containing a link with parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, smtp, visual-studio-2013

I'm new in asp.net. I'm building a web-based application with C#, and I thought a lot about how to authenticate the user by his ID using the email.

I searched about it and I tried this code but it didn't worked because it sends a page rather than link with ID.

```
 string URI = "http://localhost:49496/Activated.aspx";
 string myParameters = "param1="+id.Text;
 string HtmlResult = "";
 using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
 {
     wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
     HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
 }

 MailMessage o = new MailMessage("f@hotmail.com", EMPemail, "KAUH Account Activation", "Hello, " + name + "<br /> Your KAUH Account about to activate click the link below to complete the activation process <br />" + HtmlResult);

 NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential("f@hotmail.com", "______");
 SmtpClient smtpobj = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587);
 smtpobj.EnableSsl = true;
 o.IsBodyHtml = true;
 smtpobj.Credentials = netCred;
 smtpobj.Send(o);
```

I need the ID in the activation page to change the "Activated" column from NO to YES.

Now my question: is the idea to authenticate the user by sending the ID secure?if it is,How can I perform it?

Answer (score 1):

**Best way to authenticate the user**

You can easily create a 'secure' authentication by creating a hash, with for example MD5 or SHA1. The information you hash could be, for example, appending the e-mail and user ID as a string. You can save the hash inside the database for fast comparision (that you do when the user clicks the link with the hash you created). When the hash is inside the database, the authentication is complete.

You could also append the e-mail to the link, so you are 99.9999% sure. This is, however, not really needed as the end user does not know the ID.

**Sending the page instead of the link issue**

You are adding the `HtmlResult` that contains the content of the page you requested with `wc.UploadString`. Create the link inside the e-mail body manually using HTML:

```
MailMessage o = new MailMessage("f2@hotmail.com", EMPemail, "KAUH Account Activation", "Hello, " + name + "<br /> Your KAUH Account about to activate click the link below to complete the activation process <br /><a href=\"" + URI + "?" + myParameters + "\">Click here</a>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would definitely look at encrypting the ID that you will have in the URL. Just leaving the ID blank can leave you vulnerable to attacks.

Also if your body is html you should be able to add the link in the body with something similar:

```
string sURL= "http://localhost:49496/Activated.aspx?sID=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(id.Text);
```

then add the following to your HTML body:

```
<a style='text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold;' href='" + sURL+ "'>Click Here to Activate</a>
```

and to get the ID in the  activation.aspx.cs page:

```
string sID = Uri.UnescapeDataString(Request.QueryString["sID"]);
```

Comment: Thanks alot @BossRoss , but how can I get the ID from the URL in the activation page ?

Comment: Please take note of the first code snippet edit(I have added "sID=" to the URL) then to get the ID in the activation page: string sID = Request.QueryString["sID"];

Comment: Edited to my answer to be a little more clear about the activation page ID retrieval. Should my answer be your solution then please don't forget to mark it as the answer for other users.